# Why does my adapter disconnects me from the AP when I change the MAC address of WLAN1

Tags: wireless-networking

I have [TP-Link TL-WN722N](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-11_TL-WN722N.html) Wi-Fi Adapter (Atheros chip).

I have tried changing MAC address of using [MACChanger](https://github.com/alobbs/macchanger) and some built-in commands in Ubuntu.

However, everytime I connect to the AP, the Wi-Fi adapter disconnects me and the MAC reverts to original state and then connects again.
I am changing MAC to bypass MAC filtration.

Comment: I don't think you've given enough information for anyone to help you. Are you trying to use a WiFI network that has MAC address filtering on and you're computer's MAC address isn't whitelisted?

Comment: yes very correct

Comment: So you are asking for help to invade someone's network, possibly committing a crime in the process.

Comment: No ... Its a lab setup by me ...

Answer (score 0):

802.11 requires that, to send traffic through an AP (wireless router), every client (as identified by a unique MAC address) must first authenticate (a 2- or 4-packet exchange) and then associate (another 2-packet exchange) to the AP.

If a client tries to send traffic through the AP without first authenticating and associating, the AP will send it a Disassociate or Deauthenticate frame effectively kicking it off the network until it does what's required to properly join the network. Since clients are only identified by their MAC address, if you change your MAC address, the AP sees you as a different client. It has no way to know that this new traffic from this new MAC address is from the same physical client WNIC as the previous authentication and association your card did under its original MAC address.

After you change the MAC address of your card, you need to tell it to authenticate and associate to the AP using the new MAC address, or that MAC address will receive a Deauthenticate frame, kicking it off the network.

You shouldn't assume that your wireless driver/firmware/hardware has the smarts to handle two MAC addresses at a time. This is sometimes called "virtual STA", "vSTA", "Virtual Station" functionality. [I've even seen it called a "STA VAP" for "STAtion mode Virtual Access Point". This is a misnomer that came about because the first time anyone created the ability for a single WNIC to handle more than one MAC address, it was for the sake of creating multiple Virtual APs (VAPs), and the "VAP" name stuck for virtual extra MAC address functionality, even when used for STA or WDS mode as opposed to AP mode.]

As for why your driver/firmware/hardware is resetting to its old MAC address every time it gets disconnected from the network, well, that's probably an implementation detail that will require you to inspect the source code of your driver and maybe your card firmware to understand.

Comment: but the access point is open

Comment: @RishabhUpadhyay That makes no difference. You still have to do what's called an "open system" authentication exchange, and you still have to do an association exchange.